# SupportMapFragment always null

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

i see many qustions about this but i dont find any answer to fix my problem, this is my class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapa, container, false);

    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = fm.getMap();

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    options.position(LOWER_MANHATTAN);
    options.position(BROOKLYN_BRIDGE);
    options.position(WALL_STREET);
    googleMap.addMarker(options);
    String url = getMapsApiDirectionsUrl();
    ReadTask downloadTask = new ReadTask();
    downloadTask.execute(url);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(BROOKLYN_BRIDGE,
            13));
    addMarkers();
    return v;
}
```

and my layout is this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

i have this error

> Process:  PID: 4701
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null
>   object reference
>               at greetrack.estg.ipvc.greentrack.Mapa.onCreateView(Mapa.java:96)

i know that my error is in fm that returns null but i dont know way...

Comment: You are using a MapView, you need use a MapFragment in your .xml
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and my layout is this

In that layout, replace `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` with `fragment`. To embed a static fragment in a layout resource, you use a `<fragment>` element.

Comment: Thks for the solution